# How to use two cin statement in c++

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, cin, statements

I am in doubt about how cin works with two statements, in my program I need to get at first, a sequence of numbers from the user and put them in a vector, and after a number B which will sum the first B elements of that vector, for example, if the user enters the sequence 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 and to B she enters 3, so the program will sum 5, 4 and 3. But the problem is that the second user input to A is handing the value to B, I used a while loop to get the sequence of values to A but from the second value the cin goes to B and then I get a out_of_range error, here is my code:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
using namespace std;

vector<int> nums;
void sum();

int main()
{
    int a;
    cout << "Please enter some numbers (press | at prompt to stop)" << endl;
    while(cin>>a) nums.push_back(a); //get a series of numbers

    sum();
}

void sum()
{

    int b,c = 0;
    cout << "Please enter how many of the numbers you wish to sum, starting from the first" << endl;
    cin>>b; //get the number of elements the user wants to sum
    for(int i = 0; i < b+1; ++i){
        c += nums[i];
    }

    cout << "The sum of the first " << b << " numbers is " << c << endl;
}
```

**The correct code**

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

vector<int> nums;
void sum();

int main()
{
    int a;
    cout << "Please enter some numbers (press | at prompt to stop)" << endl;
    while(cin>>a){
        nums.push_back(a);
}
    cin.clear();         // HERE IS WHAT
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n'); // WAS MISSING 
    sum();
}

void sum()
{

int b,c = 0;
cout << "Please enter how many of the numbers you wish to sum, starting from the first" << endl;
cin>>b;
for(int i = 0; i < b; ++i){
c += nums[i];
}
        cout << "The sum of ";
    for(int d = 0; d < b; ++d){
            if(d == b-1) cout << " and " << nums[d];
            else cout << nums[d] << " ";
    }
        cout << " is " << c << endl;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `i < b+1` as you loop condition? This should be `i < b`

Comment: @Down voter, why the vote down?

Comment: @AliAmiri Because the question can be solved by removing that simple _typo_. It's not very useful for any future researchers. Feel free to write an answer before it's going to be closed.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes, you are right

Comment: @AliAmiri Also note there's [no policy requiring to leave a comment with a downvote](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question), and that's good so.

Comment: Thank you all for answering, I already solved the problem =) @πάνταῥεῖ yes you're correct. It was a very dumb error lol, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entering `|` will set the fail bit, and trailing newline remains in stream.

So clear flags and eat the newline in oder to re-enable the input of `b`

```
#include <limits>
// ....

while(cin>>a) nums.push_back(a); 

cin.clear ( );
cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n') ;

sum();
```

Also, you should sum till `i < b` not `i < b+1`